# when dynamically creating an element, when clicking does not see attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have an array of data from which I am creating elements. And when I hang the event handler, then the dataset.container is undefined. How do I get to the attributes, or how do I create elements differently to get the data-category?

```js
const cards = [
  [],
  [],
  []
]

function renderCategory(card) {
  let str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
    str += `<div class="card card-category" data-category="${i}">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="${card[i].image}">
    </div>
    <div class="card-desc">
      <div class="card-text">${card[i].name}</div>
    </div>
    </div>`;
  }
  return str;
}
let categoryCard = cards[0];

function createCard(cards) {
  const main = document.getElementById('category');
  main.innerHTML += renderCategory(cards);
}
createCard(categoryCard)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#category').addEventListener('click', ({
    target: {
      dataset
    }
  }) => {
    console.log(dataset.category) // undefined
  })
})
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it into a [mcve]

Comment: What is the target here? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: target is a dataset value

Comment: That does not look like something I recognise as a valid target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So several things

For one, I could not recognise your `addEventListener('click', ({ target: { dataset }` construction as valid JavaScript.

I have tried to not change a lot but I

- return complete set of cards
- delegate from container correctly - clicking anywhere in the card will return the category

```js
let categoryCard;
const cards = [ 
{ image : "https://via.placeholder.com/128x90.png?text=Card1", name:"Card 1"},
{ image : "https://via.placeholder.com/128x90.png?text=Card2", name:"Card 2"},
{ image : "https://via.placeholder.com/128x90.png?text=Card3", name:"Card 3"}
]

function renderCategory(cards) {
  return cards.map((card,i) => (
    `<div class="card card-category" data-category="${i}">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="${card.image}">
      </div>
      <div class="card-desc">
        <div class="card-text">${card.name}</div>
      </div>
    </div>`)).join("");
}

function createCard(cards) {
  const main = document.getElementById('category');
  main.innerHTML += renderCategory(cards);
  categoryCard = main.querySelector(".card-category"); // first card
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelector('#category').addEventListener('click', e => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    const parent = tgt.classList.contains("card-category") ? tgt : tgt.closest(".card-category")
    console.log(parent && parent.dataset.category ? parent.dataset.category : "clicked somewhere else")
  })
  createCard(cards)
})
```

```html
<div id="category"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.target` refers to the lowest Element of the DOM tree on which the event was triggered. In other words, depending on where you click the `target` can be the card-category DIV, the card-image DIV, the card-desc DIV, the card-text DIV or the IMG element. That's why you're not able to access the data-attribute which is only set on the parent.

If you want to always get the Element to which you bound the event, use `event.currentTarget` instead. But in your case, you bound the event to the main `#category` wrapper. If you want to bind the event to the element that has the `data-category` attribute, you'll have to reorganize your code to use `document.createElement` instead of producing HTML strings.

Keep in mind you should append elements to the page before binding events to them.